# Python in Visual Studio Code not running from terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Whenever I run the Python interpreter from the terminal using the green arrow button, nothing executes, and an `>` appears in the Terminal. When I press the button again, I get `[ERRNO 2] No such file or directory`, directly preceded by my working directory path. Any idea how this happened, or what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Hi Will, you need to print-screen and show more information. I may be able to help by seeing what exactly you encountered ;)

Comment: About using Python in VSCode, you could refer to the content of this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) to check related usage.